# JSON Array Merge by Aggregation with New Key Name

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some document in my MongoDB Database Collection.

I tried some aggregation operation base on MongoDB 3.6+.

```
{
    "search_key1":"search_val1",
    "search_key2":"search_val2",
    "search_key3":"search_val3",
    "merge_array1":["SEQ1", "SEQ2", "SEQ3", "SEQ4", "SEQ5"],
    "merge_array2":["NAME1", "NAME2", "NAME3", "NAME4", "NAME5"],
    "merge_array3":[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
}
```

to

```
{
    "search_key1":"search_val1",
    "search_key2":"search_val2",
    "search_key3":"search_val3",
    "SEQ1NAME1":0.1,
    "SEQ2NAME2":0.2,
    "SEQ3NAME3":0.3,
    "SEQ4NAME4":0.4,
    "SEQ5NAME5":0.5
}
```

Can I get above result with aggregation framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve it with `$map` : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/